# scatter plot python with several y values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

Imagine that we have a list similar to this :

```py
[
    [1115, 1061], 
    [134], 
    [304, 357, 253, 359], 
    [512, 513, 514], 
    [543], 
    [576], 
    [533], 
    [130], 
    [513, 357, 358]
]
```

how can we `plot` a `scatter plot` that has the values in the `list` as it y value and the index value of the list as the x value.

As an example, y=1115 should be shown at x=1 and y=1061 should be shown at x=1 as well, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with `enumerate`:

```
li = [[1115, 1061], [134], [304, 357, 253, 359], 
      [512, 513, 514], [543], [576], [533], 
      [130], [513, 357, 358]]
for i in list(enumerate(li)):
    plt.scatter([i[0]+1]*len(i[1]), i[1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

If `enumerate` isn't familiar, explore it at a command-line:

```
eli = enumerate(li)
i = eli.next()
i[0]
i[1]

list(enumerate(li))
```

Comment: Thanks but why for [304, 357, 253, 359], it shows 3 dots and for 
[512, 513, 514] it shows 1 dot, etc.

Comment: Those dots are so close together (on a 0-1200 scale!) that you can't easily see that they overlap.

Comment: I appreciate a little explanation of the code as well.